# How to get control characters for Ctrl+Left from terminfo in Zsh

Tags: terminal, zsh, ncurses, zshrc, terminfo

I'm using `terminfo` to find out what they control sequence is for the Left (Right, ...) key in my terminal, so that I can then map it to something useful (move left) in my `zshrc` like this:

```
typeset -A key
left=${terminfo[kcub1]}
bindkey "$left" backward-char
```

(there's some other things to get this to work, see [source](http://zshwiki.org/home/zle/bindkeys)).
This is helpful because I use several terminal emulators and these control sequences change. e.g. I use Gnome Terminal on Ubuntu to `ssh` to a Debian box and then to use `tmux` inside that...

**But how can I find out the key codes for the CTRL+LEFT** (and RIGHT...) from terminfo? I'd like to map these to word left/right.

Answer (score 3):

The <kbd>control</kbd><kbd>left-arrow</kbd>, etc., are not standard terminfo capabilities.  ncurses provides these as extensions (see discussion in [terminal database](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/terminfo.src.html#toc-_N_C_U_R_S_E_S__U_S_E_R-_D_E_F_I_N_A_B_L_E__C_A_P_A_B_I_L_I_T_I_E_S)), and applications that know how to use the extensions can fetch them.

zsh's source code hints that it will use the terminfo library's *tables*, e.g., for `strnames` if available, but ncurses implements the extended names in a separate area of memory.  (The terminfo data dates to around 2005; the extension itself dates to [ncurses 5.0](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/ncurses.faq.html#latest_version) in 1999).

However, the implementation is (as of 2018) incomplete since zsh does not use the extended information to find the names.  The example given in [*ZSH for loop array variable issue*](https://superuser.com/questions/737350/iterating-over-keys-or-k-v-pairs-in-zsh-associative-array), e.g.,

```
for key val in ${(kv)terminfo}; do
    echo "$key -> $val"
done
```

gives only the predefined names.

zsh uses [**`tigetstr`**](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_terminfo.3x.html#h3-Terminal-Capability-Functions) to retrieve string-capabilities.  If you happen to know the name (or see it in `infocmp`'s **-`x`** listing) you can use that as an index for its **`terminfo[]`** array.

The extended names are based on xterm's code for modifiers, which is listed in the comment above the [`xterm+pcfkeys`](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/terminfo.src.html#tic-xterm_pcfkeys) entry in the terminal database:

- <kbd>control</kbd><kbd>left-arrow</kbd> is `"kLFT5"`
- <kbd>control</kbd><kbd>right-arrow</kbd> is `"kRIT5"`

Comment: It looks like zsh now has the ncurses extensions! This answer could be updated to reflect that.

Comment: Its source-code hasn't been modified to address any of the details mentioned.  You may be thinking of some add-on script.

Comment: Hmm. I haven't checked the source code, but I _can_ get the ncurses extended capabilities from $terminfo: `echo $terminfo[kUP5] | od -a`.